# Get detail of who is invoking webservice in C#

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a simple `webservice` which returns a `string` of message as below:

```
[WebMethod]
public string GetData()
{
     return "Here is your response";
}
```

So just to log details, is it possible to identify from which system the service has been invoked?

Comment: What you mean "which system"? System ip ? What info you need?

Comment: @BWA.. Yes.. say I have a `webservice` and are consuming/invoking it.. Now I wanna it is you who invoked the service.. Basically yea, the IP details..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `HttpContext` by:

```
string ip = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

And there is more usefull informations.

Comment: This isn't WCF service buddy.. There is no operation contract here... This is Web service...

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Then there is `HttpContext`, my bad

Answer (score 0):

You can get the host address from the OperationContext.Current. The below code would do it.

```
RemoteEndpointMessageProperty endpoint = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;
string address = endpoint.Address;
```

This will work for both self hosted and IIS hosted services. The Address might give a IPV6 address when the network is configured with it. So you may need to resolve using Dns.GetHostEntry(address) to get the IPV4 address.